# Calculate Days With Array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have modified Coopers wonderful answer from 2017 to take arguments and it works fine with two dates plucked from a sheet. But when I try to iterate thru a 1D array of dates from a sheet I get the dreaded NaN. Following is a segment of the code:

```
console.log("orderOut :" + orderOut);
console.log("orderIn :" + orderIn);
console.log("assetOutOn:" + assetsOutOn[1]);
function test() {
  var easyPeezee = getDaysHoursAndMinutes(orderOut, orderIn);
  console.log("easyPeezee:" + easyPeezee);
  var myResult = getDaysHoursAndMinutes(orderOut, assetsOutOn[1]);
    console.log("myResult :" + myResult);
}
```

which results in the following:

```
7:07:31 PM  Info    orderOut :Fri May 05 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
7:07:31 PM  Info    orderIn :Mon May 08 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
7:07:31 PM  Info    assetOutOn:Tue May 02 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
7:07:31 PM  Info    easyPeezee:3
7:07:31 PM  Info    myResult :NaN
```

The question is why no joy with a 1D array value which appears to be identical to orderOut format wise.
Here is the called function and I would expect another number when I call assetsOutOn[1]. In my real code the 1 is a variable in a loop and looking for negative numbers.

```
function getDaysHoursAndMinutes(hd, td) {
  //var hd=new Date('2022-11-21T20:23:26+0000').valueOf();
  //var td=new Date().valueOf();
  var sec = 1000;
  var min = 60 * sec;
  var hour = 60 * min;
  var day = 24 * hour;
  var diff = td - hd;
  var days = Math.floor(diff / day);
  var hours = Math.floor(diff % day / hour);
  var minutes = Math.floor(diff % day % hour / min);
  //Logger.log('%s days %s hours %s minutes', days, hours, minutes);
  return days;
}
```

Resolved by uncommenting the first two lines of the called function which gets the valueOf() the submitted dates. Sorry.....

Comment: Can you share more code such as the implementation of `getDaysHoursAndMinutes`?

Comment: And also share some sample data and the result that you are expecting.

Comment: @AngYC - I have included the getDays... code and am still stumped.

Comment: @Tedinoz - I have included the getDays... code and am still stumped.

Comment: @Cooper - Perhaps you can help me understand why this does not work with an array value which appears identical.

Comment: Is it possible that `assetsOutOn` is a 2D array?  Try `var myResult = getDaysHoursAndMinutes(orderOut, assetsOutOn[1][0]);`

Comment: Figured it out. I had commented out the first two lines which obtained the valueOf the date arguments.

Comment: You parameters must be Javascript Date() objects

Comment: Try using the Date() constructor on them

Comment: Thanks Cooper, those are the words of wisdom I have learned from this episode.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by uncommenting the first two lines of the called function which gets the valueOf() the submitted dates. Not sure why I had commented them. Changed those lines to:

```
var hd=new Date(hd).valueOf();
var td=new Date(td).valueOf();
```